# Proving that $(A \cap B) \subset A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am having great difficulty trying to understand a question I have found and am keen to finding the solution and would appreciate any help.

$(A \cap B) \subset A$  Prove this.

I did like this

If  $x \in A \cap B$ , then  $x \in A$  and  $x \in B$ .
Therefore,  $x \in A$. Is this enough and true?

Comment: Do you know what does it mean $\cap$ ? And $\subset$ ?

Comment: If an element is in $A \cap B$, then it's in both $A$ and $B$, so certainly it's in $A$. Without more information it's hard to know how to answer your question.

Comment: I did like this

If x∈A∩B , then x∈A and x∈B . Therefore, x∈A . Is this enough and true?

Comment: @studystudysucces Yes.

Comment: it is enough and true

Comment: Yes, that is enough

Comment: Assuming your $\subset$ is $\subseteq$, your answer is fine.